# Using android RtpStream to record audio and send to server

Tags: android, audio, rtp

I want to make an android app that records audio and sends it to a server.
I thought the best option would be RTP, and the android classes RtpStream and RtpGroup from package android.net.rtp.
The server, made in Python, for now just receives datagram packets and write logs.

The problem is that the server is never receiving packets.

There is not much documentation and discussions about class RtpStream. It seems no one is using it. There are better alternatives?

I checked there is no problem in connection from android to the python server. I also tried a sample from MediaRecorder to record a sample from the microphone and play it, and it works.

Here is my android activity:

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.media.MediaRecorder
import android.net.rtp.AudioCodec
import android.net.rtp.AudioGroup
import android.net.rtp.AudioStream
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnClickListener
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.io.IOException
import java.net.DatagramPacket
import java.net.DatagramSocket
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.InetSocketAddress

private const val REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200

class Demo1Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG="demo1"

    val REMOTE_HOST = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.6")
    val REMOTE_PORT = 20000

    private var permissionToRecordAccepted = false
    private var permissions: Array<String> = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
        Manifest.permission.INTERNET
        )

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        permissionToRecordAccepted = if (requestCode == REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION) {
            grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        } else {
            false
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted) finish()
    }

    override fun onCreate(icicle: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(icicle)

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION)

        val btn = Button(this)
        btn.text = "Send"

        btn.setOnClickListener{sendAudio()}
        setContentView(btn)
    }

    private fun sendAudio() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            // this is to test that there is no network connection with server:
//            val socket = DatagramSocket()
//            val bytes = "Hello from android".toByteArray()
//            val dt = DatagramPacket(bytes, bytes.size, InetSocketAddress(REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT))
//            socket.send(dt)


            val audioManager = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
            audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION // from AudioGroup doc
//            audioManager.isMicrophoneMute = false // tried this also

            val group = AudioGroup()
            group.mode = AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL


            val stream = AudioStream(InetAddress.getLocalHost())
            stream.mode = AudioStream.MODE_SEND_ONLY // also tried MODE_NORMAL
            stream.codec = AudioCodec.AMR // also tried PCMA and GSM
            stream.associate(REMOTE_HOST, REMOTE_PORT)

            stream.join(group)
//            group.sendDtmf(10)

            Thread.sleep(40000)
        }
    }
}
```

The python server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket, sys, struct

# como generalizar?
ADDR = "192.168.1.6"
PORT = 20000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((ADDR, PORT))

while True:
    BUF_SIZE = 10000
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(BUF_SIZE)

    print("received addr=%s, %s len=%i" % (addr,data, len(data)))
```

The android log:

```
D/ViewRootImpl@3dc5380[Demo1Activity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@3dc5380[Demo1Activity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/dnadroid.teste: Thread[14,tid=20852,Native,Thread*=0x7ebff23400,peer=0x158f8c80,"DefaultDispatcher-worker-1"] recursive attempt to load library "/system/lib64/librtp_jni.so"
D/AudioGroup: stream[78] is configured as AMR 8kHz 20ms mode 1
D/AudioGroup: stream[77] is configured as RAW 8kHz 32ms mode 0
    stream[77] joins group[76]
    group[76] switches from mode 0 to 2
D/AudioGroup: stream[78] joins group[76]
D/AudioGroup: reported frame count: output 820, input 320
    adjusted frame count: output 820, input 512
D/AudioGroup: latency: output 202, input 64
```